# How does this 'chain rule manipulation' work?

Tags: integration, derivatives, physics

**PS- this is a "physics" question, but mathematical in nature... if I should ask on physics SE instead, please let me know**

Looking back through my physics books, I found a derivation of Kinetic Energy, where it begins by defining work ($W$) as the integral of the sum of all forces acting on an object over the distance that the object moves:

$$W = \int_{x_i}^{x_f}\sum\vec{F}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

It then goes through some manipulations (using Newton's second law ($F = ma$) and acceleration being the derivative of velocity) to perform the following:

$$W = \int_{x_i}^{x_f}ma\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{x_i}^{x_f}m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}x $$

And then it claims that it uses "chain rule manipulations" to do this:

$$\int_{x_i}^{x_f}m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{x_i}^{x_f}m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{v_i}^{v_f}mv\,\mathrm{d}v$$

What's going on here, exactly?

- Why were they able to use the definition of the chain rule? (Under what conditions could you do this?)
- Why did the integrand compress into $v\,\mathrm{d}v$?
- Does the fact that $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$ became $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ tell us that $v$ is a function of $x$, and $x$ is a function of $t$?
- Why is there a change of variable in the limits of integration?

Comment: The issue I have with $\frac{dv}{dx}$ is that this derivative only exists if $v$ is a continuous function of $x$. But for this to be the case $v$ must have only one value for a given $x$. To me this is not obvious if the particle moves back and forth - surely one would need to invoke conservation of energy to show that $x_1=x_2 \implies v_1=v_2$? I think it may make sense though if the particle moves through very small intervals of time, and displacement, such that there is no possibility of moving "back and forth" in any interval. To do this in "one shot" from $t_1$ to $t_2$ seems dubious.

Comment: @Marconius, this is taken care of by the limits of integration (which are not circular), else another approach is used (e.g thermodynamics). So it is valid to use this under these conditions.

Comment: @NikosM. - I can see that, hence the mention of small intervals. Obviously, $\int_{v_3}^{v_4}{f_1(x) dx} = -\int_{v_4}^{v_3}{f_2(x) dx}$ (provided $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$) as well, so a motion that reverses itself may simply result in cancellations . I just think a lot of potential issues are glossed over in the explanation, and can see why the OP might be skeptical. In any case, I think Ian's answer is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your third line they are breaking up $$ \frac{dv }{dt}$$ into
$$  \frac{dv }{dx}* \frac {dx}{dt} $$
notice that dx values cancel when they are multiplied together (essentially multiplying by $$ 1=\frac{dx}{dx}$$ From here the  right term $$ \frac{dx }{dt}$$ becomes velocity and the left term $$ \frac{dv}{dx}$$ cancels with the original dx from the integral to leave dv.

So essentially they multplied by 1 (dx/dx) to change the expression into mv rather than ma.  The chain rule always applies but we don't usually keep track of it.  For instance, if $y=x^2$ then $dy/dx=2x*dx/dx$ but $dx/dx=1$.

Maybe you already understood this and are asking something else, but if not I hope this helps.

Comment: ah ok - I didn't note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ showed up - that makes sense! But what's with the change of integrating factors?

Answer (score 1):

This is just integration by substitution, which is inspired by the chain rule: $\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}$, so that we can change the integration variable from $x$ to $v$, "morally" by saying $\frac{dv}{dx} dx = dv$. The real story uses the chain rule and the FTC, but this is the idea. Note that when you integrate by substitution, you *really* update the limits: that is, integration by substitution would suggest that $\int_a^b u(x) u'(x) dx = \int_{u(a)}^{u(b)} u du$ (abusing notation slightly in the latter expression).

This will only work provided $x$ is continuously differentiable and its derivative never changes sign. If that is violated, then you have to split the integral or perhaps even deal with a path integral in certain situations.